# Equicontinuous problem: supremum of equicontinuous functions

Tags: general-topology, continuity, supremum-and-infimum, equicontinuity

Suppose $X$ is a metric space. Let $S$ be a subset of $C(X)$ which is the set of continuous real-valued functions on $X$. If $S$ is equicontinuous and bounded, define 
$g:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that for every $x\in X$, $g(x)=\sup \{f(x)| f\in S\}$

Show that $g\in C(X)$

I am not sure how to do this problem.

I think since $S$ is equicontinuous you have $\forall \epsilon>0$ $\exists \delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x-y|<\delta$ for all $f\in S$

Comment: Try writing out the proof when $S$ has just two elements.

Comment: Actually, is $X$ given to be separable? I can give a straightforward proof in this case: take an enumeration $y_m$ of the countable dense subset, take a sequence $f_{n,m}$ in $S$ with $f_{n,m}(y_m) \to g(y_m)$. Then diagonalize. Use equicontinuity to conclude that the limit of the diagonalized sequence is $g$ and then use closedness to conclude that $g \in S$.

Comment: Is there a way to prove this using Arzela Ascoli?

Answer (score 4):

We can prove [lower and upper semicontinuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-continuity) separately.

We know that supremum of any family of continuous functions is lower semicontinuous. In fact supremum of any family of lower semicontinuous functions is lower semicontinuous. See, for example, these posts: [To show that the supremum of any collection of lower semicontinuous functions is lower semicontinuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1662726/to-show-that-the-supremum-of-any-collection-of-lower-semicontinuous-functions-is) or [Show that the supremum of a collection of lower semicontinuous function is lower semicontinuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2320814/show-that-the-supremum-of-a-collection-of-lower-semicontinuous-function-is-lower).

So it remains to show that $g(x)=\sup\limits_{f\in S} f(x)$ is upper semicontinuous. I.e., we want to show that for any $M$ the set
$$g^{-1}(-\infty,M)=\{x\in X; g(x)<M\}$$
is open.

So let $x_0$ be a point such that $g(x_0)<M$. Let us choose $\varepsilon=\frac{M-g(x_0)}2$. From equicontinuity we get that there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x_0$ such that for $x\in U$ and for any $f\in S$ we have $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\varepsilon$.

Then for every $f\in S$ and $x\in U$ we get
$$f(x)=f(x_0)+(f(x)-f(x_0)) \le f(x_0) + |f(x)-f(x_0)| \le g(x_0)+\varepsilon = \frac{M+g(x_0)}2$$
which implies
$$g(x) = \sup_{s\in S} f(x) \le \frac{M+g(x_0)}2 < M.$$

We have shown that any point $x_0\in M$ has a neighborhood $U$ such that $x_0\in U\subseteq g^{-1}(-\infty,M)$, which means that the set $g^{-1}(-\infty,M)$ is open.

Answer (score -1):

Using Ian's idea of seperating of assuming only S two element. I assume that $S $ has $f_1,f_2$.

and $f_1<f_2$ for all $x\in X$ and $f_1<f_2$ for all $y\in X$. Also we know that S is equicontinous then $\forall \epsilon>0$ $\exists \delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ when $|x-y|<\delta$

Because $g(x)=\sup f(x)$ then $g(x)=f_2(x)$ and by a similar logic $g(y)=f_2(y)$

and because $f\in S$ then $g\in S$ so then

$\forall \epsilon >0$ $\exists \delta>0$ such that $|g(x)-g(y)|<\epsilon$ when
$|x-y|<\epsilon$

Comment: You can't assume that $f_1<f_2$. Part of the point is that there might be some points where $f_1-f_2$ changes sign, at which point you switch between $f_1$ and $f_2$. You're trying to argue that at these points, $g$ is still continuous.