# Pointwise infimum of an arbitrary collection of upper semicontinuous functions is upper semicontinuous

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, supremum-and-infimum, semicontinuous-functions

A real-valued function $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is upper semicontinuous if for each $c \in \mathbb{R}$, its pre-image $f^{-1}(-\infty,c)$ is open in $X.$

In [encyclopaedia](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Semicontinuous_function#Upper_and_lower_semicontinuous_envelopes), there is the following statement:

> Let $\mathcal{F}$ be an arbitrary family of upper semicontinuous functions on a given topological space $X$. Then the function $F(x) = \inf_{f \in \mathcal{F}} f(x)$ is upper semicontinuous.

The article stated that the proof can be found in General Topology by Bourbaki, Chapter $5 - 10$. But I do not have access to that book.

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-continuity#Properties), similar statement appears.

> Likewise, the pointwise infimum of an arbitrary collection of upper semicontinuous functions is upper semicontinuous.

I manage to prove the statement holds for countably many functions, its proof is similar to proving infimum of measurable functions is measurable, but I have no idea on how to prove for arbitrary case.

Comment: See also: [Show that the supremum of a collection of lower semicontinuous function is lower semicontinuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2320814) and [To show that the supremum of any collection of lower semicontinuous functions is lower semicontinuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1662726)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$F(x)<c\iff\exists f\in\mathcal F [f(x)<c]$$
so that: $$F^{-1}(-\infty,c)=\bigcup_{f\in\mathcal F}f^{-1}(-\infty,c)$$
If the $f\in\mathcal F$ are upper semi-continuous then this is a union of open sets, hence is open.